How should a LWM2M client handle an observe request that overlaps, but isn't equivalent to, an existing observe?
Suppose a lwm2m server has an observation on /9, and it makes a request to observe /9/0, or /9/0/7.  Or, vice versa, it has an existing observation on /9/0 and requests to observe /9.
What should the client do?  Should it allow both observations to be installed, even though there is an overlap in the resources being observed?
The lwm2m specification doesn't provide specific guidance on this.
